# Understanding Difference of Scala/Java App versus CLI for base64(sha256("foobar"))

Tags: scala, base64, sha256

Why does the following `Scala` program not output the same result as the following command-line result for base64-encoding the result of applying a SHA256, i.e. `base64Encode( sha256( "foobar" ) )`

#### CLI

```
$echo -n "foobar" | openssl dgst -sha256 | base64
YzNhYjhmZjEzNzIwZThhZDkwNDdkZDM5NDY2YjNjODk3NGU1OTJjMmZhMzgzZDRhMzk2MDcxNGNhZWYwYzRmMgo=
```

#### Scala REPL

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
import java.util.Base64

val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("sha-256")
val inputBytes: Array[Byte] = "foobar".getBytes("UTF-8")
md.update(inputBytes)
val sha256d: Array[Byte] = md.digest()
val base64d: Array[Byte] = Base64.getEncoder().encode(sha256d)
new String(base64d, "UTF-8")

// outputs the following

res5: String = w6uP8Tcg6K2QR905Rms8iXTlksL6OD1KOWBxTK7wxPI=
```

Why do they output different values?

Comment: probably not very smart comment, but still: are you sure in the command line the "foobar" is UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: That's a good question, Alexander. No, I'm not sure.

Comment: try `echo $LANG`

Comment: `$echo $LANG` returns `en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo -n "foobar" | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 | base64`

I think `-binary` flag gives you in essence the same as `Array[Byte]` result type in Scala. So it is safer to feed to Base64 encoder array of bytes than something we are not sure what :)

Comment: I've updated a bit. Actually `openssl base64` is the same as `base64`, so it was not essential.

Comment: `-binary` is essential, and this is the correct answer.